# Asp.net webapi exclude route from matching more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

I have the following routes set up in my webapi..

```
        //Route for getting the api access token
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "AccessTokenRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/access-token",
            defaults: new { controller = "AccessToken" }
        );

        //Default route for the api
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I have a controller called AccessTokenController.  When a request comes in with the url /api/access-token, everything works fine.  It hits the appropriate controller.

My problem is that if a request comes in at /api/AccessToken, it will also match the default route. I want to prevent the route from matching if they access it that way.  Is there anything that exists in the routing system to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constraint to your DefaultApi route that restrains the access if the controller is AccessToken.

Comment: Is there a way to do that with the constraint.  I have tried setting controller to the following regex with no success. 
.... constraints: new { controller = @"[^AccessToken]" }

Comment: I'm not good at using regex, so I created a class that implements IRouteConstraint and it worked.

Comment: try constraints: new { controller = @"^(?!.*accesstoken).*$" }